# Socket.io Typescript Custom Arguments

Tags: typescript, socket.io

I have a question. I'm trying to use Socket.io with Typescript.

Therefore I'm using this definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts

Now to my question. How does I have to use the socket.once method, when I send the custom arguments "example: true" using the socket.emit method?

My code for the NodejS server:

```
socket.once("example-event-request", {
    socket.emit("example-event-response", {example: true});
});
```

Browser when need the data:

```
socket.emit("example-event-request");

socket.once("example-event-response", (data) => {
    this.example = data.example;
});
```

---

Added as an Answer (likely to be deleted soon):

> I want to specify this more. I need to write this JavaScript code in
>   Typescript using the linked definitions.
>
> ```
> this.socket.once(eventName, function(){
>     callback.apply(this.socket, args);
> });
>
> this.socket.emit(eventName, data, function(){
>     callback.apply(this.socket, args)
> });
> ```
>
> The problem is that I cannot get the args because there is no
>   Typescript variable for this.

Answer (score 1):

The `emit` and the `once` *cannot be on the same side*. You emit from server to client or client to server. And the `once` belongs on the other side.

Also `"{example: true}"` should probably be `{example: true}` i.e. a json serializable object (not a string).

## More

if you are looking to do `rpc` I have an example project (alm) that abstracts that over socket io (or inter process ipc): https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/contributing/async.html

Comment: You was totally right. My example code was wrong. I updated it.

Comment: which one is the `server` (node js server) and which is the `client` (browser) in your updated question

Comment: Upps, the Webserver example is the browser. Fail.

Comment: In that case the server `.once` should be on a *browser client socket* i.e. the socket you get after a client connects. Is that correct?

Comment: The Angular2 Component needs the data and sends the request. The server is listening on the request event and emits the response event with data back. Then the Angular2 Component (The browser) listen on the response event and it do something with the data.